# Dependence of sign of integral

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, monotone-functions

suppose that $f,g : \mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ are differentiable functions such that f is strictly increasing and g is strictly decreasing. Define $p(x) = f(g(x)$ and $q(x) = g(f(x)),\forall x\epsilon\Bbb{R}$. then for t>0, the sign of $$\int_{o}^{t}p'(x)(q'(x)-3)dx $$ is

a. positive
b. negative
c. dependent on t
d. dependent on f and g

Comment: Is there any connection between increasing/decreasing  and the sign of derivative?

Comment: Increasing functions have +ve derivative while decreasing functions have -ve. Also the absolute value of derivatives tells us how fast a function increases or decreases (depending on the sign).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is a): it is easy to verify that $p$ and $q$ are both decreasing. Hence $p'$ and $q'$ are both negative. Hence the integral is positive.

Comment: Can we intuitively understand why p and q are decreasing

Comment: Yes. If you start with $x<y$ one function keeps the inequality and the other one reverses it. When you apply both one after the other the in equality is reversed.